# My code gives me an error "no such file or directory"

Tags: python

I have a bunch of data classified as follows:

```
sl00
   snap_000
   snap_001
   snap_002
sl01
   snap_000
   snap_001
   snap_002
sl02
. 
. 
and so
```

My code:

```
IC_folder = r'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ICs' #folder where all the ICs are stored 
snaps_folder = r'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\outputs_all\\sl%02d'%ifile

files = os.listdir(IC_folder) #get all ICs
snaps = os.listdir(snaps_folder) #get all snaps

nfiles = len(files) #find how many ICs there are
nsnaps = len(snaps) #find how many snaps there are

for isnaps in np.arange(nsnaps):

    tMyr, radius, nHp, nHep, nHepp, temp , redshift , overden, veloc, omegaM, omegaL, gH0, nH0, ngrid, h100, omegab  = readsnap("snap_%03d"%isnap)

    current_a=1./(redshift+1)
    #Units of variables  #temperature in K
    vel=(veloc*units.km/units.s).to(units.cm/units.s) #peculiar velocity in cm/s
    #cell position (radius) from ckpc/h to cm
    h=0.7
    rad=(((radius/((1+redshift)))/h)*u.kiloparsec).to(units.cm) #radius in cm
    #a_dot and H(z=3)
    a_dot = np.sqrt(omegaM/current_a + omegaL*current_a**2 )*H0 
    H_z = a_dot / current_a
    #Hubble velocity for each pixel v_H= d*H
    v_H=rad*H_z
    #velocity of the absorber: Hubble velocity + peculiar velocity 
    v_i=v_H + vel
```

The first time, somehow it worked but not anymore. The directories correspond to the place where the data is but still, I got an error of `no such file or directory` or `ifile is not defined`. I would appreciate some help because I am not sure what is wrong there.

Comment: well ifile is not defined...  What is the Ifile variable supposed to represent?  In the second line of your script you are attempting to do string formating on a file path with a variable `ifile` but ifile is never declared.  also at the end of the `readsnap` function the `isnap` variable doesn't exist either...  also the function `readsnap` is never declared either

Comment: ` r'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\outputs_all\\sl%02d'%ifile ` this path is wrong check for %ifile and %02d it looks like path of web then change %02 with " "

Answer (score 0):

I saw you code and in first and second line, r'' is not needed
Thanks